# Removing more than one symbol in importhtml data output

Tags: google-sheets

I tried following formula.....
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/BAJFINANCE","Table",1)and was able to get the data but with two symbols - and *. Now I want to remove * and - symbol to be replaced by zero. How to do that plz ???

Comment: Only - symbol to be replaced by zero not the * too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTHTML("https://niftyinvest.com/option-chain/BAJFINANCE","Table",1),"-", "0"), "*", ""))
```

Comment: niftyinvest.com/max-pain/AARTIIND?expiry=30JUN2022
Here on black strip wretten as "MAX PAIN FOR AARTIIND IS 740". Can you help me to retrieve that 740 digit plz. One more request that here can you make the formula in general so that I can use it for many stocks and different dates of expiry plz.